# WCF and Entity Framework 6 config file

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, connection-string

I've a WCF service defined inside a library and a windows service which self-host this WCF service. I use Entity Framework 6 for Data Layer inside same library.

Who could confirm where I should defined connection string needed for EF?
Inside app.config of my self-hosting Windows Service? ie WindowsService.exe.config...

I want that this connection string would be available for all my WCF clients...

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally my issue was not related at all to app.config(s).

I didn't call correctly my WCF service.

To avoid proxies generation/use, I use ChannelFactory() in my WCF Service because I manage both servers and clients. This WCF Service is implemented throw MVVM Light with following code:

ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            //Define data access (wcf service) for design mode
            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            ...
    }
```

WcfServer class:

```
public class WcfServer : IDisposable
    {
        //Wcf connection
        private ChannelFactory<IService> _wcfFactory = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the DataService proxy from MVVMLight SimpleIOC instance.
        /// </summary>
        public IService DataService
        {
            get
            {
                return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>()??null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a Wcf server for a customer, a url and a server name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="customerName"></param>
        /// <param name="serverName"></param>
        /// <param name="urlServer"></param>
        /// <param name=""></param>
        public WcfServer(string customerName, string serverName, string urlServer)
        {
            _customerName = customerName;
            ServerName = serverName;
            UrlServer = urlServer;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connect to wcf service
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if a null exception is thrown all over Connect method</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">Thrown if an object is disposed all over Connect method</exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException">Thrown if authentication failes with username/password over ssl</exception>
        /// <exception cref="CommunicationObjectFaultedException">Faulted Exception on exception from ChannelFactory==>CreateChannel</exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Invalid Operation Exception</exception>
        /// <exception cref="Exception">Other exception</exception>
        /// <returns>Returns true if connected</returns>
        public bool Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                ...

                EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(UrlServer));
                if (_wcfFactory == null)
                {
                    _wcfFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(WCFSharedConfiguration.ConfigureBindingWithSimplehttps(), endpointAddress);

                    //Open ChannelFactory
                    _wcfFactory.Open();

                    //Define Faulted handler
                    _wcfFactory.Faulted += FactoryFaulted;
                }
                else
                    //Log + return
                if (!ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
                {
                    //If we are not in Design (means blend or VS IDE)
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IService>(() => _wcfFactory.CreateChannel(), true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log
                throw;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disconnect current channel
        /// </summary>
        /// <exception cref="TimeoutException">Timeout</exception>
        /// <exception cref="CommunicationObjectFaultedException">Faulted Exception on exception from ChannelFactory==>CreateChannel</exception>
        /// <exception cref="Exception">Other exception</exception>
        /// <returns>True if successfull</returns>
        public bool Disconnect()
        {
              ...
        }
```

May it helps!